# Comment functionality on every page in Yii 1.1

Tags: yii, yii1.x

I am using Yii 1.1.16 for one of my projects.

I have 5 controllers at the moment, and their data is coming from their respective models.

Now I want to add new functionality into my website, regarding comments. I want to add a form at the bottom of each view, but obviously the data will be coming from another database table (I have created a new model for that).

I am confused. Should I create 5 different forms in HTML for my problem, or can I use Yii widgets functionality to implement the same?

The Comment table would be the same for every user in the database. Comments will be coming with the help of their user id, which is stored in the table, and their comment will be inserted with the help of their user id, too.

Please let me know the best solution you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create one widget for displaying comments section and one controller for handling request from this widget (for example adding new comment or displaying different page of comments list). In this way adding comments for any section should require only few lines of code to initialize widget:

```
$this->widget('CommentsWidget', [
    'parentId' => 'page-' . $model->id,
]);
```